# Pass value to a key in html from a script file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, script#

I have an html file where I need to render the app id that will come from a script sharp (.js.cs) file. Do you know how I can set this up?

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-app-id="value" src="https://xyz.js"></script>
```

Thank you,

Edit: Including more details if needed.
I have an html file which has script like above, it renders scripts from a source location. But there when the solution is deployed, each Organization will have it's data-app-id which will be coming from back end. I have this value in a .js.cs file, but how to set it in the above script at run time?

Comment: please elaborate your question a bit, probably its just me but nothing makes sense

Comment: You need to extract data-app-id attribute from script tag and place it to HTML ?

Comment: No. I have the data-app-id value in hand but want to set that at run time to the above script so that the html will have different data-app-id for each Organization when solution is deployed.

Comment: Make the `xyz.js` file dynamically-generated and pass the variable as parameter...would it be ok for your needs?

Answer (score 1):

add js file to your project and define a variable in it

```
 var myValue="";
```

set the `data-app-id= myValue`

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-app-id=myValue src="https://xyz.js"></script>
```

and then you can update this variable in  what ever place you want

Comment: Sorry I didn't get this. I have the above script in an html file only.
Can you please provide more inforamtion?